Difference between a Function and the name of a Function
I am currently studying the book by Loeb and Hurd on Nonstandard Analysis. In the chapter "simple languages for relational systems" they differ between an mathematical object like a function $f$ and between the name of that function $\underline{f}$.
Why is this distinction necessary?

I believe they simple want to make it explicit when they're working with the mathematical objects and when they're forming sentences in a language. The only motivation for this seems to be the transfer principle which is framed in terms of simple sentences.

We have mathematical objects, like numbers, and names for them, that are expressions of the language we are using to speak of objects. There is Napoleon and many ways to name it: Napoleon, Bonaparte, the first French Emperor.

Without knowing the book for context, I imagine it's much like the difference between a dog named Fido and the name of the dog, "Fido".

This is a general phenomenon in mathematics and is not limited to logic.  For example, one of the axioms of a group is the existence of a "neutral" element $e$.  When you work with a specific group, $e$ will be implemented accordingly as $0$ in the case of the integers $\mathbb Z$ and $1$ in the case of the multiplicative group $\mathbb R^+$.
As noted in the comments, in nonstandard analysis there is a concrete need to specify a language to which the transfer principle applies.  However, this in itself does not necessitate making the distinction that Loeb and Hurd make.  For example, Goldblatt's book

Goldblatt, Robert.
Lectures on the hyperreals.
An introduction to nonstandard analysis.
Grad. Texts in Math., 188
Springer-Verlag, New York, 1998

(a better one, in my opinion) does not make the specific distinction between $f$ and $\underline f$, which shows that it is not really indispensible.
